# Enlarging a Hole made by a Hole Saw

Tags: drilling, drill-bits, hole-saw

I drilled several holes in my desk to put some grommets using a 7/8" hole saw bit.  Unfortunately, I realized afterwards that the hole was supposed to be 1" to fit my grommets.

Then, despite knowing better, I used my 1" hole saw bit in an attempt to make the holes the correct size.  Although I was able to make the hole larger, the new hole did not come out clean at all.

The obvious solution to this would be to clamp a piece of plywood behind the hole to use as a pilot.  However, the position of the holes make this solution pretty unfeasible - they are in the back of the shelf of a large hutch - i would need to get a very long piece of wood with some huge clamps in order to make that solution work (unless I am missing something):

[image]

What is the best way of fixing this?  I could get the next larger size of grommet (1.5") and make the hole larger, but which bit would be the best for this task?  I have never used a Forstner bit - but it looks like it might be promising.  Thoughts?

Comment: I have to check but I am sure we have covered this. This one is close http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/410/enlarging-a-stepped-through-hole but there an option not mentioned there.

Comment: Do you have a slightly longer drill bit which you can use as pilot drill (the one coming with a hole saw usually is embarrassingly short)? If it's longer than the work piece's thickness, this is a breeze, just need to put any old piece of wood under the hole.

Comment: @Damon - I don't think this is a feasible solution - check my update above with additional details about the positioning of the hole.

Comment: If the holes are in back, and the edges will be covered by the grommet anyway, this may not be worth trying to fix.

Comment: I would think that an 8' (or so) 2x4 could be clamped horizontally behind where the holes need to be, and used as a backer for the pilot bit. If you've built this desk, I'd guess you've got at least 2 bar clamps deep enough to span the hutch riser + 2x. (I'm envisioning that the holes all go at the grey drawer level - the 2x can run behind those drawers.)

Comment: I had just arrived at @Freeman's solution when I decided to recheck the comments.  This assumes that you are drilling from the rear and that you have a couple of clamps that will open to about 12"

Comment: Should work OK from the front, as well, @AstPace. There should be plenty of room from the front to locate the pilot bit into the 2x backer board, and OP can adjust the hole location anywhere he wants to. One would assume that he won't shift it so far that the new hole won't completely overlap the old one, though.

Comment: @freeman I had thought that, too, plenty of room for the bit, but decided it might be a good trick to get a drill and a hand to operate the drill into the drawer slot simultaneously.

Comment: Carpet tape.  You can attach the backing board using double-sided tape, and not need huge expanse and awkward clamps.

Comment: @FreeMan - Definitely good advice in theory - the only problem is the picture i posted is only part of a big desk (it's a u shaped with attached bookcases, etc).  It would take all day to take it apart to get behind the hutch - I am going to try an Oops Arbor and see if I can get it working without uprooting my whole office -

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lee Valley (I'm sure you can get it elsewhere) sells a product called an [Oops Arbor](http://www.leevalley.com/en/Wood/page.aspx?p=52518&cat=1,180,42316&ap=1) that allows you to mount two hole saws to a single arbor.  The smaller one is held further out from the larger one allowing it to support itself as it drills.

[image: from http://www.leevalley.com/en/images/item/woodworking/drilling/30n0390-inset.jpg][image: From http://www.leevalley.com/en/images/item/woodworking/drilling/30n0390s.jpg]

Comment: That is exactly what I need!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Never saw those!  Awesome

Comment: I've seen hole saws before where the height of the blades increased as the diameter decreased, but I never realised why — until now. Thank you!

Comment: If only  you could use that to make the holes smaller.

Comment: [This](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/400/ef/efc1fb1c-81b1-4ded-8eba-98cfe00f2d42_400.jpg) is what you use to make holes smaller, @Matt

Comment: Someone tell my SO that I want this for my birthday.

Answer (score 5):

If you are unable to move the piece or provide additional access (as you describe), then another approach might be to cut a wood plug the same diameter as the current hole and glue it in place in the hole.  Once it is set up you can begin drilling again using the larger bit.

Comment: And as a bonus - if the holesaw in question uses a centering bit, the plug will have a centered hole for cutting the larger hole in the original surface.

Answer (score 3):

If you and can disassemble the piece and have a router with a rabbet bit, you can enlarge the hole by going around with depth set less than the full thickness of the material and the bearing against the edge of the hole.

Then flip the piece over, attach a bottom-bearing flush-trim bit, and set the depth so it bears against the edge of the rabbet you just cut.

You can calculate the width of the cut by subtracting the diameter of the bearing from the diameter of the rabbeting bit and dividing by two.  E.g. if your rabbet bit is 3/4" diameter has a guide bearing of 1/2", it would give you the extra 1/8" you need, as would any combination of bit/bearing where the difference in diameters = 1/4".

Answer (score 1):

With your 1.5" holesaw, cut a nice hole in a chunk of scrap plywood. Clamp this to the location of the old hole, and drill away.

(Unless you plan to wrestle your desk to a drill press, the forstner will do you no good at all.)

Comment: I don't think this is a feasible solution - check my update above with additional details about the positioning of the hole.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this very problem. Existing 22mm holes and needed 30mm. Went to my wood supplier and got a short length of 22mm dowel. Cut off short lengths to suit depth of existing holes. Glued around the rim at the top of the hole and hammered the short dowel lengths in flush to work surface. When dried, re-cut holes to new 30 mm dimension.
Mike